# Not able to update xcode 6

Tags: macos, xcode6

I'm not able to update my Xcode to 6.1. I'm not able to build an app on my device which 
has iOS 8. After Googling I found I have to update Xcode but I'm not able to do that.

Getting this error:

> There was an error in the App Store. Please try again later. (13).

Comment: I think this question should go to http://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: You should check your apple id and password as well as your connection to the internet.

Comment: You can also sign in to developer.apple.com and download the non-App-Store version and install that after throwing out the one you have.